# Restricting stripe shipping address by country

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am selling a physical product through Stripe Checkout (the native stripe version) and I'm looking to lock the shipping address to UK.

Has anyone any info on how this can be configured? Can't find it in docs.

Answer (score 2):

If using the javascript client integration, you can specify the allowed countries if you enable shipping address collection.

```js
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      ...
      shippingAddressCollection: {
        allowedCountries: ['DK'],
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something supported by Stripe Checkout at the moment. The best solution here would be to collect the shipping address in your own form before opening Stripe Checkout and only collect billing address in Checkout (or no address at all).