# Is it possible to limit countries for the shipping address in the Stripe SDK?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I'm working on an app for a product which will only be available to ship to the USA and Europe at launch.  It appears that the Stripe SDK by default allows any country to be selected in the shipping address.

The only thing I could find on this topic was [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951776/restricting-stripe-shipping-address-by-country) from a year ago, not sure if this has changed.

This must be a common use-case - is there a way to configure white-listed countries for shipping, or else what is the intended way to handle this?